# Unable to access global variable outside of JavaScript API Fetch

Tags: javascript

I am using Fetch with an API and storing the results in a global 
variable but it causes an error, saying that the global variable, 
'res', where I have stored the results of the API call is undefined.

I have tried using let and var to define the global variable.

```
    var res;
    fetch(  "https://api.taboola.com/1.2/json/apitestaccount/recommendations.get?app.type=web&app.apikey=7be65fc78e52c11727793f68b06d782cff9ede3c&source.id=%2Fdigiday-publishing-summit%2F&source.url=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.taboola.com%2Fdigiday-publishing-summit%2F&source.type=text&placement.organic-type=mix&placement.visible=true&placement.available=true&placement.rec-count=6&placement.name=Below%20Article%20Thumbnails&placement.thumbnail.width=640&placement.thumbnail.height=480&user.session=init"
    )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            res = data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    const contentArr = res.list;
```

I am expecting to be able to access the variable `res` outside of 
the Fetch. but when I assign 'const contentArr = res.list;' it says 'res' is undefined

Comment: You're retrieving the global variable too early, the value will be there only after the fetch will be finished.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a flow of your code :

1) var `res` is declared.

2) You start fetching data from external resource, and it takes some time. It's not done instantly.

3)  Execution of your code continues even though fetching of data has not finished yet.

4) You try to assign to  `contentArr`  `res.list` , however, `res = data;` has not executed yet, therefore you get `undefined`.

You can understand better by reading about event loop in JS.

Comment: How can I access the contents of the Fetch?